# std::_Atomic_thread_fence (with capital A) is this correct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

The Visual Studio 2012 c++ documentation states that `_ReadBarrier` and `_WriteBarrier` intrinsics are now [deprecated:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z055s48f(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The `_ReadBarrier`, `_WriteBarrier`, and `_ReadWriteBarrier` compiler
>   intrinsics and the MemoryBarrier macro are all deprecated and should
>   not be used. For inter-thread communication, use mechanisms such as
>   `atomic_thread_fence` and `std::atomic<T>` that are defined in the C++
>   Standard Library Reference. For hardware access, use the /volatile:iso
>   compiler option together with the `volatile` (C++) keyword.

Following the indications, I then jump to the `atomic_thread_fence` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874633(v=vs.110).aspx) and it states that the function is defined on header `<atomic>`.
If I include such header on my solution, I can't find the function, but I do find  `std::_Atomic_thread_fence` instead.

The naming suggests me this is a Microsoft-specific implementation.  Is this a documentation problem or should I modify perhaps the default `#include` search paths?

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I can definitely see `atomic_thread_fence` in `<atomic>` on my VS2012. `_Atomic_thread_fence` is in `<xatomic.h>`.

Comment: Using vs 2013, this happens to me as well, however when I correct it to `atomic_thread_fence` manually it works fine.

Comment: @T.C:  you are totally right,  I didn't notice that if I jump to "open definition", the file that is actually opened is  `<xatomic.h>` which is actually included by `<atomic>`   -  Thanks!

Comment: @Phantom: indeed,  it works.  It seems to be an intellisense snafu. If you post your coment as an answer I will gladly accept it. Thanks too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to simply be a problem with the Visual Studio intellisense. If you correct it to `atomic_thread_fence` it should work just as intended.